# Raise Header's Z-Index Over Material UI Modal Backdrop

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm building a mobile version of a web app using Material UI and having trouble matching designs. I'm using [MUI App-Bar](https://mui.com/components/app-bar/) together with [MUI Modal](https://mui.com/components/modal/) to create something similar to the mockups shown below.

The expected behavior is that the user selects the button in the top right of the header to open the modal, and has the option to use the top right button again to close the modal. The user should also be able to select `My App` logo in the header to navigate to the home page.

The actual behavior is that the header bar is covered by the modal's backdrop; I can add styling like `marginTop: 150px` to the backdrop to visually achieve the expected result, but the button and the logo are still not usable.

Is there a way to override the backdrop component so that the header will be usable?

[image: No Modal on left, Expected behavior in middle, actual on right]

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
  card: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: "160px",
    width: "90vw",
    borderTopLeftRadius: "0px",
    borderTopRightRadius: "0px",
  },
  backDrop: {
    marginTop: "160px",
  },
}));

const Header = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [menuOpen, setMenuOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleOpenUserMenu = () => {
    setMenuOpen(true);
  };

  const handleCloseUserMenu = () => {
    setMenuOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <AppBar
      position="static"
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
        zIndex: -1,
      }}
    >
      <Container maxWidth="xl">
        <Toolbar>
          <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
            <Link to={"/home"}>
              <Logo className={classes.logo} />
            </Link>
          </Box>
          <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 0 }}>
            <IconButton onClick={handleOpenUserMenu}>
              <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Modal
              open={menuOpen}
              onClose={onClose}
              BackdropProps={{ classes: { root: classes.backDrop } }}
            >
              <Card className={classes.card}>
                <CardContent>
                  <MenuItems menuOptions={menuOptions} />
                </CardContent>
              </Card>
            </Modal>
          </Box>
        </Toolbar>
      </Container>
    </AppBar>
  );
};
```

Comment: I don't think the header (navbar) will be usable after modal is opened , as modal covers full width and height and but try giving header z-index : 99 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [MUIModal documentation](https://mui.com/components/modal/) the modal component is supposed to behave like that I would try to use menu component instead

Quoting documentation:

> If you are creating a modal dialog, you probably want to use the Dialog component rather than directly using Modal. Modal is a lower-level construct that is leveraged by the following components:
>
> - Dialog
> - Drawer
> - Menu  <--
> - Popover

Comment: Originally started with a Menu but couldn't get it to function the way I wanted it to visually. Will go back and give it another try